Trying to understand better the solution for $L \ regular \to L'=\left \{ xy^{R}z : xyz\in L\ , x,y,z\in\Sigma^{*} \right \} \ regular$
In this post:
For a regular language $L$, is $\{xy^Rz:xyz\in L\}$ regular?
@Hendrik Jan have give a really good answer but I'm failing to understand it.
I have looked at $L=\left \{ abc \right \}$ in order to understand the answer.
Here is an autumaton for $L$ :

As I understand it, it holds that:
$\bigcup_{p,q} L(\mathcal A_{q_0,p})=\left \{a,ab,abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{p,q} L(\mathcal A_{p,q})^R=\left \{a,b,c,ab,ba,bc,cb,abc,cba \right \}$
$\bigcup_{p,q} L(\mathcal A_{q,F})=\left \{c,bc,abc \right \}$
Thus $w=abccbaabc \in L'= \bigcup_{p,q} L(\mathcal A_{q_0,p})\cdot L(\mathcal A_{p,q})^R\cdot L(\mathcal A_{q,F})$
I would like to know where is my mistake.

The correct answer (edited)
@Hendrik Jan helped me to see my mistake:
$\bigcup_{q_0,q_0}=L(A_{q_0,q_0})\cdot L(A_{q_0,q_0})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_0,F})=\left \{ abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_0,q_1}=L(A_{q_0,q_0})\cdot L(A_{q_0,q_1})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_1,F})=\left \{ abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_0,q_2}=L(A_{q_0,q_0})\cdot L(A_{q_0,q_2})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})=\left \{ bac \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_0,F}=L(A_{q_0,q_0})\cdot L(A_{q_0,F})^{R}\cdot L(A_{F,F})=\left \{ cba \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_1,q_0}=L(A_{q_0,q_1})\cdot L(A_{q_1,q_0})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_0,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{q_1,q_1}=L(A_{q_0,q_1})\cdot L(A_{q_1,q_1})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_1,F})=\left \{abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_1,q_2}=L(A_{q_0,q_1})\cdot L(A_{q_1,q_2})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})=\left \{abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_1,F}=L(A_{q_0,q_1})\cdot L(A_{q_1,F})^{R}\cdot L(A_{F,F})=\left \{acb \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_2,q_0}=L(A_{q_0,q_2})\cdot L(A_{q_2,q_0})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_0,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{q_2,q_1}=L(A_{q_0,q_2})\cdot L(A_{q_2,q_1})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{q_2,q_2}=L(A_{q_0,q_2})\cdot L(A_{q_2,q_2})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})=\left \{abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{q_2,F}=L(A_{q_0,q_2})\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})^{R}\cdot L(A_{F,F})=\left \{abc \right \}$
$\bigcup_{F,q_0}=L(A_{q_0,F})\cdot L(A_{F,q_0})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_0,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{F,q_1}=L(A_{q_0,F})\cdot L(A_{F,q_1})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_1,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{F,q_2}=L(A_{q_0,F})\cdot L(A_{F,q_2})^{R}\cdot L(A_{q_2,F})=\emptyset$
$\bigcup_{F,F}=L(A_{q_0,F})\cdot L(A_{F,F})^{R}\cdot L(A_{F,F})=\left \{abc \right \}$
Thus, we get:
$\bigcup_{p,q} L(\mathcal A_{q_0,p})\cdot L(\mathcal A_{p,q})^R\cdot L(\mathcal A_{q,F})=\left \{ abc,acb,bac,cba \right \}$

Note that in $\bigcup_{p,q}$ the states $p,q$ are variables, ranging over $Q$. That means we have four possibilities each. (Also $F$ in the original answer was intended to represent the set of final states and it is a single state here. But that is only a detail.)
So we choose, eg, $p=q_0$ and $q=q_2$. Then $L(\mathcal A_{q_0,p}) = \{\varepsilon\}$, $L(\mathcal A_{p,q}) = \{ab\}$ and $L(\mathcal A_{q,F}) = \{c\}$. This leads to a contribution of $\{\varepsilon\}\cdot \{ab\}^R\cdot \{c\} = \{bac\}$ to the big union. Fifteen more to go (except that half of them will contribute the empty set.)

Thank you for the answer. I edited the post. I'm still trying to figure out in "simple" words why this give the desired result but I'm failing to do this. May I ask for additional explanation?

Not much to  add, I am afraid. The new language is found by swapping a segment of an accepted string. The formula "guesses" this segment is read between state $p$ and state $q$ and divides the accepting path onto three segments: from $q_0$ to $p$ to $q$ to a state in $F$. These paths can be described as finite automata, and are glued together after inverting the middle segment/automaton. We need to do this for each $p,q$ separately in order not to glue paths that do not fit together.

"divides the accepting path onto three segments: from $q_0$ to $p$ to $q$ to a state in $F$" - from there it connected. You are the best !!
